# Prove that formula is or is not a tautology

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to figure out how to decide whether the given (predicate logic) formula is a tautology or not and prove it.

$$ \forall x\exists y\exists z\forall u(R(x,y)\land R(z,u))\leftrightarrow  \exists x\forall y\forall z \exists u(R(x,y)\land R(z,u)) $$

I can't figure out how to start. I was thinking about getting rid of Quantificators.

Could you give me some hints or help me to solve it?

Comment: $t$ doesn't appear on the right-hand side, and $u$ is free. Is this a typo?

Comment: Is it on purpose that the right-hand side has $\exists t$ but still $u$ in $R(z,u)$?

Comment: Thank you guys, I've corrected the mistake. There should be U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rules
$$ \forall a(P\land Q(a)) \leftrightarrow P\land \forall a(Q(a)) 
\qquad\text{when $a$ is not free in }P \\
\exists a(P\land Q(a)) \leftrightarrow P\land \exists a(Q(a))
\qquad\text{when $a$ is not free in }P  $$

to push the quantifiers down below the $\land$ on each side. Once that is done you will find that the two sides are identical up to renaming of bound variables and commutativity of $\land$.

Comment: This is a hint for why the formula is logically valid; it is not obvious whether the OP is asking about validity or about tautologies (cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540933/how-to-check-whether-the-formula-is-a-tautology )

Comment: @CarlMummert: Since the formula is clearly not a substitution instance of a propositional tautology (the only propositional formulas, up to renaming, that have this as a substitution instance would be $A\leftrightarrow B$ and $A$, neither of which is a tautology), I chose the interpretation that would make the question more interesting.