# How to check, whether the formula is a tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

How do we decide whether the formula in predicate logic is a tautology? Is there some universal way to decide?

Let's have an example:

```
Vx(P(x)&Q(x))<->VxP(x)&VxQ(x)
```

My solution (not correct and not complete)

So the first thing I do is to rename some variables on the right side.

```
Vx(P(x)&Q(x))<->VxP(x)&VyQ(y)
```

No, I can do this:

```
Vx(P(x)&Q(x))<->Vx(P(x)&VyQ(y))
```

And this:

```
Vx(P(x)&Q(x))<->VyVx(P(x)&Q(y))
```

So my question is:

How can I decide and proove, whether it is a tautology?

Comment: **Hint:** It isn't.

Comment: @GitGud I know that it isn't a tautology but this is a simple example. In more difficult examples it is not that simple I think. And I'm looking for some way to proove that it is not a tautology.

Comment: Are you asking whether the formula is logically valid, or whether is is a "tautology" in the more restricted sense of first-order logic?

Comment: @CarlMummert I'm asking whether the formula is valid in any interpretation of the language.

Answer (score 2):

I quote from Wikipedia:

> [A tautology in first-order logic is a sentence that can be obtained by taking a tautology of propositional logic and uniformly replacing each propositional variable by a first-order formula (one formula per propositional variable).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic))

In propositional logic a tautology is a formula which evaluates to be true for every possible substitution of truth values of its variables.

---

In the example

$$\forall \,x \,(P(x) \land Q(x))\iff \forall \,x \,P(x) \land \forall \,x\,Q(x)\tag 1$$

we have the following different first order formulas:

- $\forall \,x \,(P(x) \land Q(x))$
- $\forall \,x \,P(x)$
- $\forall \,x\,Q(x)$

These will be replaced by $A,B$, and $C$, respectively. We get

$$A \iff B\land C$$

which is **not** a tautology; its truth value depends on the truth values of the variables.

$(1)$ would be a tautology of first order logic if we could create it by the reverse substitution from a tautology of propositional logic.

---

For another example take the propositional tautology

$$A\land B \Rightarrow A\lor B$$

and let's do the following substitutions:

- $A$ : $\forall \,x \,(\exists \,y \,Q(x,y))$
- $B$ : $\exists \,y \,P(y)$.

Now, we have

$$\forall\, x \,(\exists \,y \,Q(x,y))\, \land \,\exists \,y \,P(y) \Rightarrow \,\forall \,x \,(\exists \,y \,Q(x,y)) \lor \exists \,y \,P(y)$$

which is a tautology of the first order logic because it could be obtained by a substitution of first order expressions into a propositional tautology.

Comment: I don't know enough about this subject to provide an answer myself but I think your explanation is incorrect or at least incomplete. If we replace the $\Leftrightarrow$ with $\Leftarrow$, then (1) does become a tautology, but your replacement still renders it as $A \Leftarrow B \wedge C$.

Comment: Oh never mind, apperently not every logically valid formula is a tautology.

Comment: @zoli, I've found out that this particular formula is a tautology in meaning that it is valid in any interpretation of this language. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

To tell whether the formula is true in every interpretation, the first step is to think through what each side of the formula says about an interpretation. The left side
$$
(\forall x)[P(x) \land Q(x)]
$$
says that $P$ and $Q$ hold of every object $x$ in the interpretation. The right side
$$
(\forall x)[P(x)] \land (\forall x)[Q(x)]
$$
says that $P$ holds for every object $x$ in the interpretation, and so does $Q$. Since the right and left sides both say that $P$ and $Q$ hold of all objects, the right and left sides will be equivalent in every interpretation.

Here is an example that is not valid in every interpretation:
$$
(\forall x)[P(x) \lor Q(x)] \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)[P(x)] \lor (\forall x)[Q(x)]
$$
The left side says that, for each object $x$, at least one of $P$ or $Q$ holds. The right side says that either $P$ holds of every object, or else $Q$ does. That is clearly not the same thing! And it naturally suggests an interpretation: let the objects be natural numbers, let $P(x)$ say "$x$ is even", and let $Q(x)$ say "$x$ is odd". Then the left side of the compound formula above holds in this interpretation, but the right side does not. You should treat falling back on formal proofs to verify a formula as a kind of last resort when more intuitive methods fail.

This method (think through what the formula means) is much faster than blindly trying to use inference rules to deduce a formula.