# Decide whether logical formula is a tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, quantifiers

How do we decide whether the formula in predicate logic is a tautology? Is there some universal way to decide and prove it?

Let's have an example:

$$ \forall x \forall z \exists y\,(P(x,y) \lor P(y,z)) \leftrightarrow \forall x \exists y \forall z\,(P(x,y) \lor P(y,z)) $$

I was adviced to choose some Universum and it's realisation but I don't know how to do that.

Could you help me to solve it?

Comment: This question was already asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540933/how-to-check-whether-the-formula-is-a-tautology#comment3138117_1540933 ; please do not ask the same question multiple times. Replacing "and" with "or" does not change the general way to solve the question. Moreover, you did not answer the question I asked in a comment on the other question: do you really want to ask about logical validity, or are you really asking about the more restricted notion of a tautology in first-order logic?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is (provably) *no universal method* to determine whether a formula in first-order logic is logically valid. We say that first-order logic is **undecidable**.

**If** the formula is logically valid, it will have a formal proof (in each of the various proof systems for first-order logic).

On the other hand, if it is **not** logically valid, then there will be a structure that does not satisfy the formula -- but there's no guarantee that such a structure will have a definite description from which one can *prove* that it doesn't satisfy the formula.

If the formula is complex enough it is *possible* that it can neither be proved valid or proved not-valid.

So in general it's up to cleverness and creativity.

---

For your concrete example, we first observe that the formulas on the two sides of $\leftrightarrow$ are both *closed* -- i.e. they have no free variables -- so each of them will simply be *true* or *false* about any structure (a set with a relation $P$) we apply it to.

The formula is then logically valid if every possible relation either satisfies both sides or *doesn't* satisfy either side.

We can further see that the difference between the two sides is that the one to the left has $\forall z \exists y$ where the one on the right has $\exists y \forall z$. This makes the right one *harder to satisfy* then the left one (because on the left $y$ is allowed to depend on $z$), so if there is a counterexample, it has to be a relation $P$ that satisfies the left-hand side and *doesn't* satisfy the right-hand side.

What does the right-hand side say, then?
*(Rest of answer removed; it was based on a horrible failure to notice what the actual symbols in the formula were)*

Comment: Thank you Henning for your answer. But I have one question about it. I feel like you work with ANDs instead of ORs. For example, you've written: "For any two x and z there needs to be an y that "sits between them" in the sense that  x≺y≺z". I think that this would be correct if there were x<y & y<z but there is x<y OR y<z which means that y don't have to sit between them or am I wrong?

Comment: @user337105: Hmm, you're indeed right. That kills the last half of my analysis.